# Merge multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi array and I need to combine it with other. This array is made for send in XML format to SOAP, so it need to have the correct structure.

This array is like an invoice, it have "items" which i have to repeat. So, i think in make two arrays (one have always the same structure) and add the items array.

The problem is that if I use merge, I could not put the second array in the correct key. Here an example.

This is the correct array structure:

```
$params = array( 
        'authRequest' => 
        array( 'token' => 'token',
                'sign' => 'sign',
                'cuitRepresentada' => 'CUIT' ), 
        'comprobanteRequest' => 
            array(  'codigoTipoComprobante' => $codtipcbte,
                    'numeroPuntoVenta' => $ptovta,
                    'numeroComprobante' => $cbte,

                    **'arrayItems' =>
                        array( 'item' =>
                            array(
                                array(
                                'tipo'=> $compreqitem['tipo'],
                                'codigoTurismo'=> $compreqitem['codTur'],
                                'descripcion'=> $compreqitem['descrip'],
                                'codigoAlicuotaIVA'=> $compreqitem['codAlic'],
                                'importeIVA'=> $compreqitem['impIva'],
                                'importeItem'=> $compreqitem['impItem'],
                                ),
                                array(
                                'tipo'=> $compreqitem['tipo'],
                                'codigoTurismo'=> $compreqitem['codTur'],
                                'descripcion'=> $compreqitem['descrip'],
                                'codigoAlicuotaIVA'=> $compreqitem['codAlic'],
                                'importeIVA'=> $compreqitem['impIva'],
                                'importeItem'=> $compreqitem['impItem'],
                                ),
                                ),

                            ),**



                    'arraySubtotalesIVA' =>
                        array( 'subtotalIVA' =>
                            array(
                                'codigo'=> $compreqiva['codIva'],
                                'importe'=> $compreqiva['importe'],
                                ),

                             ),
                     ),

        );
```

So, i build the array with "arrayItems" empty

```
'arrayItems' => array(),
```

Then i build the arrayItem array:

```
$arrayitems =
    array('arrayItems' =>
                        array( 'item' =>
                            array(
                                array(
                                'tipo'=> $compreqitem['tipo'],
                                'codigoTurismo'=> $compreqitem['codTur'],
                                'descripcion'=> $compreqitem['descrip'],
                                'codigoAlicuotaIVA'=> $compreqitem['codAlic'],
                                'importeIVA'=> $compreqitem['impIva'],
                                'importeItem'=> $compreqitem['impItem'],
                                ),
                                array(
                                'tipo'=> $compreqitem['tipo'],
                                'codigoTurismo'=> $compreqitem['codTur'],
                                'descripcion'=> $compreqitem['descrip'],
                                'codigoAlicuotaIVA'=> $compreqitem['codAlic'],
                                'importeIVA'=> $compreqitem['impIva'],
                                'importeItem'=> $compreqitem['impItem'],
                                ),
                                ),

                            ),
                        );
```

Then i use merge to join both array:

```
$resultado = array_merge($params['comprobanteRequest'], $arrayitems);
```

Works, but the first key is deleted...

```
'authRequest' => 
            array( 'token' => 'token',
                    'sign' => 'sign',
                    'cuitRepresentada' => 'CUIT' ),
```

I dont know why is deleted, maybe the merge function is not the corect way...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your first array, `arrayItems` is always empty, then you don't need a merge, just set the value :

`$params['comprobanteRequest']['arrayItems'] = $arrayItems['arrayItems'];`

Of course this can be simplified, since `$arrayItems` contains only one key, but you get the spirit.

Comment: Thanks! I do it this way because i dont know how many items will have the invoice.